# Docker and cron is broken: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid

Tags: debian, cron

On my unRAID server, I am trying to run a Docker container with cron installed and enabled. Here is my very, very simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron nano

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

The container starts and everything looks fine, however, when I go into the container and type `cron`, I get this error:

> cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 7: Resource temporarily unavailable

I have tried to just do `CMD tail -f /var/log/cron.log` to keep the container alive, but the result is the same. `service cron status` shows cron is running.

What else do I need to do, to get cron working on a bare minimum Debian Buster image?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `cron` is already running!

Try:

```
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

to keep the container running while you try things manually

Comment: Cron was not running, unfortunately. I ended up going with scripts instead, so my cron is handled in unRAID insead.